# Geofire Query in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, geofire

Sorry for my english, I have a doubt it is possible to make a query geofire in Firebase Cloud Func, with their respective key_enter and key_exited, in order to maintain a list of the geographic points near my position ?, extracted from a few hundred thousand. Taking into account that all this happens when the user updates its geolocation in a node firebase realtime database, and this list of hundreds of thousands is reduced to a few near the position of the user

Comment: Given that Geofire is a library built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, it can access the Firebase Database in the same way. Writing to the database is exactly the same. But listeners will work differently. I recommend you give it a try and post back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a trick I used to update with GeoFire

```
exports.testLocation = functions.database.ref('/tests/{test}').onWrite(event => {
    let data = event.data.val();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(event.params.test);
    if (data.location && data.location.coords) {
        console.log('Update GeoFire');
        geoBase = new geoBase(event.data.adminRef.parent.parent.child('/GeoFireTests'));
        geoBase.addLocation(event.params.test, [data.location.coords.latitude, data.location.coords.longitude]);
    }
});
```

GeoFire

```
let GeoFire = require('geofire');
module.exports = function(ref) {
    this.geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
    this.addLocation = (key, location) => {
        this.geoFire.set(key, location).then(() => {
            console.log('Update succesfull');
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonas, Can you please explain what is the 2nd part of your answer

Comment: Sorry, the second part is a separate module that is imported into the first part. It is used here: geoBase = new geoBase().

Answer (score 0):

**This is how it would look like without the module**

```js
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let GeoFire = require('geofire');

exports.testLocation = functions.database.ref('/items/{item}').onWrite(event => {
    let data = event.data.val();
    console.log(data);
    console.log(event.params.item);

    if (data.location && data.location.coords) {

       console.log('Update GeoFire');

       let ref = event.data.adminRef.parent.parent.child('/items_locations'));

      let key = event.params.test;
      let location = [data.location.coords.latitude, data.location.coords.longitude]);
      let geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

      geoFire.set(key, location).then(() => {
         console.log('Update succesfull');
   }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
   });

  }
}
```